# store data from database table in a global variable to use any time

Tags: sql-server, web-services, xamarin.android

I've created an android app using Xamarin.android. my app has a listview whose rows are filled with data that I get from sql server via an asmx webservice. It also has a popup menu that also gets its data from the database table. and when I click on a row from the listview a dialog fragment is shown with info about the row clicked. I get those info from the same database table using a webservice function that filters the table to get the info corresponding to the item selected. what I mean is that whenever I need to fill something in my app I create a web function in my asmx webservice and use it in my app. so I was thinking, is this efficient? is it okay? or is it better to store the data of the database table in a global variable in my app and whenever I need to do something I just perform some actions on it?
any advice is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Well the most efficient service call is the one not made so some common sense local caching will improve performance. But you need to consider other factors like whether the database data might change, whether the latest data are required, and resources needed for caching locally.

Comment: ohh okay, I got it. thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use as few web service calls as possible, as the highest number of crashes in mobile apps is mainly due to external services not working as they are supposed to. So, try to code your app to where it can receive null responses from the services, or there is some sort of error while parsing the response data.

If you have an application that is used by a lot of users, reducing the number of API calls will reduce the load on your servers. And in the case where you are using a cloud App Service which is charged based on API call, it's best to also reduce API calls. The best way of doing that is by caching as much as possible.

For caching in Xamarin, I highly recommend using a service like [Akavache](https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache) to properly manage data coming from your services, so that you can cache in the best way while keeping in mind time limits and type of storage of cache.